"Truthy" statements in eight characters
Suppose we have a "language" consisting of the "characters" $\{1,+,-,\times,/,(,),=\}$, where each string must have exactly one $=$. An "truthy" statement is a (finite or countably infinite) string in said language that corresponds to a true statement in the real numbers ($+1$ and $-1$ are allowed as numbers). For example, $1+1+1=1+1+1$ is truthy, $1+1-1=1+1+1$ is not, while the truthiness of $1//++1=1$ is undefined because it is meaningless. Statements about a nonexistent object, for example $1/(1-1)=1$, are considered undefined. This also applies for infinite strings. $1=1+(1-1)+(1-1)+…$ is truthy, because you are just adding zeros forever, and it is NOT an indeterminate form because the limit of adding zeros forever is $1$. However, the truthiness of $1=1+1-1+1-1…$ is undefined, because the right side may or may not equal $1$ depending on where parentheses are placed on it.
Then, how do I prove whether the "truthy" statements, in the languge described above, form a countable set? My first guess is that the statements with undefined truthiness have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, but I have not confirmed that.

Won't there be $2^{\aleph_0}$ "truthy statements" of the form $1=1+S_1+S_2+S_3+\cdots$ where each $S_n$ is either $(1-1)$ or $(1+1-1-1)$?

Do all infinite strings have the order type of $\Bbb N$ or can they have the order type of $\Bbb Z$?  I seriously doubt that matters to the answer to your question but it may affect the proof.

You encode real numbers in the interval $[0, 1)$ in binary using your "truthy" statements.
For example: $0.0101$ as
$(1-1)=(1-1) \times 1 \times (1-1) \times 1 \times 1 \times (1-1)$
The initial $(1-1)$ on the RHS ensures that the value is always $0$ to match the LHS.  We can follow it with a sequence of $(1-1)$ and $1$ to match the desired value.
So the cardinality is at least that of the reals.  It is not hard to see that it cannot be bigger either.

However statements are finite and therefore the set of statements can only be countable.

@Peter The OP says "finite or countable infinite string".
